# MS Access - VBA - Cloning a Table

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access

I wanted to basically copy the entire content of one table to another.

Context:

- Table source is SharePoint list and triggers an email per record being queried. No way to turn it off on my end as it's being utilised by another team.
- When I run my queries on a local table, it's fine.

I need to just copy the data directly. So far, the only code I found is

`DoCmd.TransferDatabase` but I can't seem to configure it correctly.

Comment: What is the complete command you attempted? Edit question. Review https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/synchronize-a-sharepoint-2010-list-with-access-2010-975bfb97-c799-4fce-b7cc-3db3b397f116

Comment: You could open the designer SELECT ALL and run a make table query as well.  there is a spot on the designer ribbon to turn a select into a make table query.

Answer (score 1):

Simplest method is probably to run a make-table query to (re)create the local table:

```vb
Dim Sql As String

Sql = "SELECT * INTO LocalTable FROM SharePointTable;"
CurrentDb.Execute Sql
```

That will pop a warning, though. If that is too much, create the local table, then run two queries - the first to delete all records from the local table, the second to append all records from the SharePoint table to the local table.